# iOS - Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am writing an iOS app in Swift which needs to display a various static HTML files in a `WKWebView`.

My plan is to create a View Controller with an [`@IBInspectable`](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/) property for the name of the file to display. The `HTMLViewController` will load the file specified and then create a `WKWebView` to display it.

When I run the app in the simulator (or on my device) and load the view, I get the following error message in the Xcode console:

> Failed to set (filePath) user defined inspected property on (*MyApp*.HTMLViewController): Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/*me*/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A5982A49-71CD-4F06-ABD7-01EBBF001698/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/032D479A-091B-4FAB-9CB8-82DC72B99E89/*MyApp*.app> (loaded)' with name 'pyN-vU-Kur-view-0DN-tc-q8g'

The app does load and run. The HTMLViewController is set up to be a "show" segue from an accessory on a UITableView. Only when I tap the accessory does this error appear. The app still shows the (empty) view, I am able to use the navigation controller to go back to the UITableView just fine.

Using some `grep`, I found that `pyN-vU-Kur` is the Object ID for the View Controller, and `0DN-tc-q8g` is the ID of the UIView inside it.

I checked my Build Phases, and noted that the storyboard is listed in the Copy Bundle Resources section. I thought perhaps it was just an issue where a reference got broken in my storyboard, so I deleted the scene and recreated it, but am still seeing the same error. I also saw some posts that talk about checking the Target Membership in the inspector. I have verified that the `content` folder which contains the HTML file, the storyboard, and the view controller all have the target membership box checked.

Debugging reveals that the HTML file is being loaded (I had the content logged to the console) and the `applyContent` method is being called, and the error seems to occur on the call to `WKWebView()`.

My `HTMLViewController.swift` code is below:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

@IBDesignable
class HTMLViewController: UIViewController {    
    @IBInspectable
    var filePath: String! = "" {
        didSet {
            if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filePath, ofType: "html", inDirectory: "content") {
                do {
                    let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
                    self.applyContent(html: contents)
                } catch {
                    print("problem reading file \(filePath)")
                }
            } else {
                print("problem locating file \(filePath)")
            }
        }
    }

    func applyContent(html: String) {
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
    }
}
```

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it? I am relatively new to Swift and iOS development, so I may be missing something basic.

Comment: do you changed from "Main storyboard file base name" to "Main nib file base name" in the plist ?

Comment: @Nazmul No, I did not change that in my plist. I just tried that, and the app won't even start up at all -- it immediately crashes with a similar error, except now it can't find Main. In my case, the app does load and run, I only see that error when I navigate to the view. Also, it does not crash the app (I can navigate back to the previous view just fine). Will update the question with these details.

Comment: changing the bundle identifier on the storyboard for new scene

Comment: @NazmulHasan I'm not sure what you're asking. I did not change the bundle identifier in my Info.plist, and I don't see any place to specify the bundle identifier on the storyboard itself. As far as I can tell, the storyboard is being loaded since I can use views contained within it with no problems, it is just when I try to open this particular view that I get the error.

Comment: well ..  Open the Identity inspector for your class, select the property name under User Defined Runtime Attributes

Comment: @NazmulHasan I don't see that section in the inspector for the HTMLViewController class. Do you mean for the storyboard? I have the `filePath` defined there and it is being set correctly and the file is being loaded -- the error seems to be coming from the call to `WKWebView()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be that you're trying to add the `WKWebView` to the `view` when it hasn't been loaded yet.

`IBInspectable`s are set very early in the process of loading the view. Try adding your `WKWebView` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

@IBDesignable
class HTMLViewController: UIViewController {    
    @IBInspectable
    var filePath: String! = ""

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filePath, ofType: "html", inDirectory: "content") {
            do {
                let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
                let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
                webView.loadHTMLString(contents, baseURL: nil)
                self.view.addSubview(webView)
            } catch {
                print("error loading file")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct, putting the code in `viewWillAppear` solved my issue! The exact code you posted didn't quite work -- should I update your answer with the exact code I used to load the file?

Comment: Absolutely, edit away! I was going off the top of my head.